# combine a drop down with a sorted list, that can be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML and Javascript but i try my best.

I have the following problem: I want to make a  Button that can be clicked so that a drop down menu is opend in which a tabe of data is listed. From this dropdown Menu the user should be able to press a number that is than inserted in a input box.

```
var table = document.getElementById("arbeitszeit");
if (table != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
                tableText(this);
            };
    }
}

function tableText(tableCell) {
    document.getElementById("arbeitszeitjeha").value = tableCell.innerHTML;

}
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="Bodenpreisrechner">
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <section class="row">
            <div class"col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="lohn"> Durchschnittliche Arbeitszeit je Hektar
                        <input id="arbeitszeitjeha" input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="..."  placeholder="Stunden/ha">
                    </label>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="hilfe" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Hilfe
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>

                        <ol class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="hilfe">
                        <table id="arbeitszeit" height="auto" class="gridtable" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>10ha</td>
                            <td>50ha</td>
                            <td>100ha</td>
                            <td>Individuel</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Marktfrucht</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><a href="http://daten.ktbl.de/vrpflanze/prodverfahren/start.action#start" target="_blank">KTBL</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Milchvieh</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><a href="http://daten.ktbl.de/wkrtier/?tx_ktblsso_checktoken[token]=" target="_blank">KTBL</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Veredelung</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><a href="http://daten.ktbl.de/wkrtier/?tx_ktblsso_checktoken[token]=" target="_blank">KTBL</a></td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to include that table in a drop down menu?

Kind regards,
JKS

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to make a self made css drop donw menu. use a ul for your names and such and li for the data

```
  <ul><li>Marktfrucht</li>
  <li>Milchvieh</li>
  <li>
    Milchvieh
    <ul>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>10</li>
  <li>10</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Veredelung</li>
</ul>
```

Next do some css magic to add the drop-down functionality
Here is just a quick example d

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,     sans-serif;
      padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #557;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try it as soon as I am home!

Comment: awesome! let me know if you need when the the click events/ getting the data into a input box